# Weird situation loading js pages in javaEE with Glassfish

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Here's the thing: when I try to load a page that doesn't exists (for example http://localhost:8080/XXXX/kgdfkjcd), the 404 error page should appear. But instead, the page loaded is http://localhost:8080/XXXX/, and I can't figure out why !

And this is also a problem for my css/js files : 
I tried to put a test.js file under webContent folder, and to load it with the code line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

It is a simple javascript file where I just put :

```
console.log("test")
```

Then, I reload, I check the console and see :

```
test.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

That's right, apparently, the file test.js is not found and the http://localhost:8080/XXXX/ page is loaded instead. (of course when a js file starts with...

```
<DOCTYPE....
```

... there is a javascript problem.

I searched a lot in a lot of forums but I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

Anyone has a solution ?

Here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>XXXX</display-name>
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/header.jsp</include-prelude>
      <include-coda>/WEB-INF/footer.jsp</include-coda>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.orvif.config.InitilisationApp
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't find the solution, but I know where is the problem... it's glassfish. I tried to use completely tomcat and it works... If someone find other solution, don't hesitate.